# Stop Animation Between Loop CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this code and i want to stop animate between loops for ex 5sec,
I was googled and found just rotate (no delay)

```css
.line-1{
    border-left: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.75);
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
 direction:ltr;
}

/* Animation */
.anim-typewriter{
 animation: typewriter 4s steps(44) 1s infinite normal both,
    blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(44) infinite normal;
}
@keyframes typewriter{
 from{width: 0;}
 to{width: 24em;}
}
@keyframes blinkTextCursor{
 from{border-left-color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);}
 to{border-left-color: transparent;}
}
```

```html
<p class="line-1 anim-typewriter" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">Good News: You Won :)<a href="Awards/"> Get Award </a></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another step in your keyframe animation that is the same as the previous step:

```css
.line-1 {
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  direction: ltr;
}


/* Animation */

.anim-typewriter {        
  animation: typewriter 8s /* increase to 8s so you have 4s pause */ steps(44) 1s infinite normal both, blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(44) infinite normal;
}

@keyframes typewriter {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 24em;
  }
  100% {  /* 50% of this animation is now a pause */
    width: 24em;
  }
}

@keyframes blinkTextCursor {
  from {
    border-left-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  }
  to {
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="line-1 anim-typewriter" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">Good News: You Won :)<a href="Awards/"> Get Award </a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.line-1{
    border-left: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.75);
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
 direction:ltr;
}

/* Animation */
.anim-typewriter{
 animation: typewriter 4s steps(44) 1s 2 normal both,
    blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(44) 2 normal;
}
@keyframes typewriter{
 from{width: 0;}
 to{width: 24em;}
}
@keyframes blinkTextCursor{
 from{border-left-color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);}
 to{border-left-color: transparent;}
}
```

```html
<p class="line-1 anim-typewriter" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">Good News: You Won :)<a href="Awards/"> Get Award </a></p>
```

Comment: but it is just two timed , not infinite

Comment: please check on  https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-events-